# How to put element of nested Arraylist in identity hash map

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I would like to populate an identity hashmap with two ArrayLists one is called barve of type String the other is nested ArrayList called clusters of type TockaXY.

Im trying with for loop and with .put but, eclipse is saying:

```
The method put(List<String>, List<List<Main.TockaXY>>) in the type Map<List<String>,List<List<Main.TockaXY>>> 
is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Main.TockaXY>)
```

The code:

```
public static List<TockaXY> noviCentri(List<TockaXY> dataset, List<TockaXY> centers) {
        List<String> barve = new ArrayList<>();
        barve.add("Modra");
        barve.add("Rumena");
        barve.add("Zelena");
        barve.add("Rdeca");
        barve.add("Vijola");
        barve.add("Crna");
        barve.add("Oranzna");
        barve.add("Roza");
        barve.add("Rjava");
        barve.add("Siva");



    Map<List<String>, List<List<TockaXY>>> barvniCluster= new IdentityHashMap<List<String>, List<List<TockaXY>>>(centers.size());
      List<List<TockaXY>> clusters = new ArrayList<>(centers.size());
    for (int d=0; d<centers.size(); d++) {
        barvniCluster.put(barve.get(d) ,clusters.get(d));
    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: The error message is expected, you're trying to insert a `String` as a key where it should be a `List` and same for the value where it should be a `List<List>` you are assigning a `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps. If it is not what you want let me know :)

```
public static List<TockaXY> noviCentri(List<TockaXY> dataset, List<TockaXY> centers) {
    List<String> barve = new ArrayList<>();
    barve.add("Modra");
    barve.add("Rumena");
    barve.add("Zelena");
    barve.add("Rdeca");
    barve.add("Vijola");
    barve.add("Crna");
    barve.add("Oranzna");
    barve.add("Roza");
    barve.add("Rjava");
    barve.add("Siva");


    Map<String, TockaXY> barvniCluster = new IdentityHashMap<>(centers.size());
    for (int d = 0; d < centers.size(); d++) {
        barvniCluster.put(barve.get(d), centers.get(d));
    }
```

...